# Bootstrap modal don't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I got problem with modals in my portfolio website. They dont show up. Trying to search for similar issues but non of answer help me in this case. I'm using bootstrap and jquery 3.3.1 and on that config modal dont show up. However when I change jquery to older for example 2.2.4 modals working fine but in my portfolio gallery with images sorting by class using script i written animation slideUp/slideDown stop working even when they was working on jquery 3.3.1.

Here is the head:

```
<head >

<!-- HTML -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

<!-- SKRYPTY -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/filtr.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>

<!-- CZCIONKI -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mina" rel="stylesheet">
```

Portfolio part of body:

```
    <div class="container" id="portfolioSection">
<h1>PORTFOLIO<br>-----</h1>
    <div class="kategorie">
        <p class="kategoria" id="all">All</p>
        <p class="kategoria" id="www">Web Design</p>
        <p class="kategoria" id="logos">Logo</p>
        <p class="kategoria" id="opak">Opakowania</p>
        <p class="kategoria" id="druk">Materiały do druku</p>
        <p class="kategoria" id="3d">3D</p>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolio-container">
        <div class="portfolio-item-container portfolio-item druk">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/lordis.jpg"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    Hello there!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-container portfolio-item www">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  src="img/strona.jpg"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    Hello there!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item-container portfolio-item logos">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  src="img/sr.jpg"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    Hello there!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="portfolio-item-container portfolio-item 3d ">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  src="img/butelka.jpg"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    Hello there!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="portfolio-item-container portfolio-item opak">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  src="img/Opakowania.jpg"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    Hello there!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And script for gallery fillter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.kategoria').click(function () {
    var kategorie = $(this).attr('id');

    if (kategorie == 'all') {
        $('.portfolio-item').slideUp(390);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.portfolio-item').slideDown(390);
        }, 400);
    } else {
        $('.portfolio-item').slideUp(390);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.' + kategorie).slideDown(390);
        }, 400);
    }
});
```

Right now I was trying just to add a regular modal example from bootstrap site.
Maybe anyone had a similar issue and is able to help.

--EDIT--

And here is modal button:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal --><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

But i cant past modal as it is because showing me some error in code but i dont see it. I just copy the example modal from bootstrap page -> components -> modal.

The edistor showing only that:

Modal title × ... Close Save changes

Comment: in the code you don't have modals

Comment: Yep i didn't paste it becaouse i didn't think it's necessary. I was trying to add it now but i can't paste modal body in code, showing me some error.